# Object.Position always goes to origin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

new to Unity here! I'm trying to move using vector3.MoveTowards(), but my object position always goes towards origin even if I placed it elsewhere. Before Play Position [Before Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYCJL.png), after Play Position [After Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4a2Z.png).

Here's my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Vector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform obj;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 a;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 b;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 c;
    public float speed;
    private RaycastHit hit;
    Vector3 previousPosition;
    Vector3 targetPosition;
    float lerpMoving;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        // speed = 100.0f;
        // hit = new RaycastHit(); 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        previousPosition = transform.position;
        // transform.position = obj.position;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);          
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) 
                {
                    LayerMask layerHit = hit.transform.gameObject.layer;

                    switch (layerHit.value)
                    {
                        case 8:
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            break;
                        default:
                            targetPosition = hit.point;
                            lerpMoving = 0;  
                            break;
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
        if(lerpMoving < 1)
        {
        movePlayer();   
        }

        void movePlayer()
        {
            lerpMoving += Time.deltaTime; 
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(previousPosition, targetPosition, 
            speed * lerpMoving);
        }

        // if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0))
        // {
        //     Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        //     if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        //     {
        //         transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(hit.point, b, speed);
        //     }

        // }


    }

}
```

This code is to make the object to move based on where your mouse clicks where beside layer 8 and 9 it can go anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are permanently moving towards `targetPosition`.

But if you never clicked and your ray has never hit anything so far then `targetPosition` will have its default value `(0,0,0)`.

And since the `lerpMoving` by default is `0` you instantly start moving.

*Note: In general your `MoveTowards` using the increasing `lerpMoving` (except the effect of increasing velocity is explicitly desired) makes not much sense. See bottom of the answer.*

---

There are multiple points and ways how to solve this.

- I would suggest to either make it e.g.

  ```
  private float lerpMoving = 1f;
  ```

  so that `movePlayer` isn't called until explicitly set to `0`.
- or you initially set

  ```
  void Start()
  {
      ...

      targetPosition = transform.position;
  }
  ```

  so it simply "moves" to where it already is now anyway.
- Or rather make sure you only move at all when the position is set. You could do this using a [Nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

  ```
  private Vector3? targetPosition;
  ```

  and later check e.g.

  ```
  void movePlayer()
  {
      if(targetPosition == null) return;

      // NOTE: See below

      if(lerpMoving >= 1f)
      {
          targetPosition = null;
      }
  }
  ```

  so you only move while there is a valid position.

---

Now I explicitly omitted the line(s) where you actually move because using an increasing `lerpMoving` as parameter for `MoveTowards` makes not much sense.

- You either want to use `Lerp` instead

  ```
  transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(previousPosition, targetPosition, lerpMoving);
  ```

  **but** in that case you do **NOT** want to update the `previousPosition` all the time but rather together with setting the `targetPosition` in

  ```
  ...
  targetPosition = hit.point;
  previousPosition = transform.position;
  lerpMoving = 0;
  ...
  ```

  in order to move to the target within 1 second after the click, regardless how far or close it is
- Or you want to move with a linear speed using simply

  ```
  transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
  ```

  and get entirely rid of `lerpMoving` and `previousPosition`.

Comment: Hi I finally got it in their original position! Thanks for your answer!!! But now my Y value always return to 0 whenever I move, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Sounds like whatever you hit (I suspect a ground plane?) is at Y = 0 then

Comment: Yes, is there anyway to make that when I move it is not fully at y=0?

Comment: Well you could simply keep your original Y and do `targetPosition = hit.point; targetPosition.y = transform.position.y;`

Comment: Yup, finally done it. Thanks!